# SK6812, what happens if a pixel fails?

Tags: led, pixels

I plan to use SK6812 RGBW LEDs for my projects.
There was a question of reliability.
What happens if one of the pixels fails? Will the signal go further?
If not, which way to look?

Comment: the daisy chained data is not dependent on the LED pixel working but the next LED is dependent on good signal being buffered

Comment: @Sunnyskyguy EE75  Thank you!!!